# Take 'snapshot' of website and load in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, load

This question is not really specific. I want to show thumbnail images of websites when hovering (its) url. With this code: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7Dy5/1/)

I can load websites in the iframe, which kinda 'resembles' a thumbnail preview. The problem is that it has to load the complete page which is not really fast and takes up quite some system performance. So my question is how can solve this problem? I can only think of two things myself:

1.Take some sort of 'snapshot' and show that snapshot instead of loading the page

2.Load only the css and other stuf but no object like movie files banner ads etc.

If those two are not done than please provide me with an alternative.

Comment: can you use any server side resources?  If you frequently have the same thumbnails, you could create images with wkhtmltoimage and load them from your server.

Comment: @trex005 No server side please, Im looking for a Jquery/javascript solution

Comment: That sound like a bad idea overall (loading full pages in iframes and pretend they are thumbnails). As you've already noticed it takes some time and uses bunch of resources to render, that will lead to terrible user experience if you'd leave it like that. Not to mention that some websites will try to breakout of the iframe using javascript so you'd end up with fighting that as well. Forget the client-side approach - go server..

Comment: You may try to use online thumbnail services, such as http://www.shrinktheweb.com , etc..